# Find all $4$ digit numbers that are perfect squares and written with $4$ even integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Find all $4$ digit numbers that are perfect squares and written with $4$ even integers.

I let the digits be $2p,2q,2r,2s$, starting from the thousands place. Then I expanded the number as $2(1000p+100q+10r+s)$. But since the number is a perfect square, the term inside the bracket must also be divisible by $2$. Hence, $s=2n$. Thus last digit is $=0,4,8$ only.

Now we have $4(500p+50q+5r+n)$. The number inside the bracket must individually be a perfect square. We know that a perfect square can only leave residue of $\equiv 0,1,4\bmod 5$ $\implies n \equiv 0,1,4\bmod 5$.

But, $0≤2s≤8 \Rightarrow 0≤2(2n)≤8 \implies 0≤n≤2$ Hence $n \equiv 0,1,\bmod 5$ only.

**Case 1:** $n \equiv0\bmod 5$

$500p+50q+5r+0$ is multiple of $5$ hence also must be multiple of $25$, only possible if $r=0$
$\implies n,r=0$. If last two digits are $0$ then we only need to check $40^2,60^2,80^2$. We see that only $80^2=6400$ is possible.

**Case 2:** $n \equiv1\bmod 5$

Here I am stuck as to what I can do. One option is just checking all the squares from $32 \rightarrow 99$ according to the needed conditions. Can someone suggest a better way?

Comment: This doesn't affect your work in any material way, and it's no help with case 2, but note that 8 cannot be the last digit of a perfect square.

Comment: @A.J. Oh yeah, that would've made my work considerably easier. It took me multiple steps to arrive at that fact. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Also note.  If $n =10a + b$ and $b^2 = 10j + k$ then $n^2 = 100a^2 + 10(2ab+j) + k$.  If $j$ is odd we are doomed.  And as $b$ is even we can't have $b=4$ or $6$ because $4^2 =16$ and $6^2 = 36$ and $1$ and $3$ are odd.  so we must have $b = 0,2,8$.  Your cases just became really few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Here I am stuck as to what I can do. One option is just checking all the squares from 32→99 according to the needed conditions. "  Well, don't check the odd ones.  And don't check $\sqrt{1000} \le n^2 \le \sqrt {1999}$ or $\sqrt{8889}\le n^2 \le \sqrt{9999}$ so that tells us to only check $46$ through $94$.

Let $n = 10a + b$ then $(10a + b)= 100a^2 + 20ab + b^2$

$b^2 = 0,4,16,36,64$.  Now if $b = 4$ or $6$ then $b^2$ will cause an odd digit to be carried of the the tens place.  And the tens place will be determined by $2ab$ plus the odd number added.  This results in an odd number.  So that is impossible.

$b^2 = 0,4,$ or $64$ and $b= 0,2,$ or $b=8$.

If $b = 0$ then we need $a^2=0,4,16,36,64$ to be a perfect square with two even digits.  That can only be $a = 8$. So

So $80^2 = 6400$ is one such number.

Now we just need to check $48, 52,58, 62,68, 72,78,82,88,92$.

But $2889...3999$ all have od digits so we don't have to check $53.. 63$.  Or $\sqrt {4889}...\sqrt{5999}$ or $70... 77$.  Or $\sqrt{6889}...{7999}$ or $83..89$.

So we only need to check $48,52,78,82,92$

$(10a + 2)^2 = 100a^2 + 40a + 4$ which means the value carried by $4a$ whether odd or even must make $a^2$ odd of even.  so the digit carried by $4a$ and an d $a$ must be the same parity.

$4\cdot 5=20$ so $2$ is even but $5$ is odd.  So $(50+2)^2 = 2500 + 40\cdot 5 + 4$ so the $2$ carried by $40\cdot 5$ to $2500$ will make $2700$ i.e $2704$.

$4\cdot 8 =32$. The $3$ is odd but $8$ is even so the first two digits of $82^2$ will be $8^2 +3$ which is odd.

$4\cdot 9=36$ and $3$ is odd as is $9$ so this is good.  $92^2 = 8100 + 360 + 4=8464$ with the $3$ and 81$ combining to make an even.

That just leaves $48$ and $78$ to check.  It's easier to just check them then to make a carrying rule.  $48^2 = 2304$. Nope. and $78^2=6084$.  Good.

So $80^2 = 6400,92^2 = 8464$ and $78^2 = 6084$ are the only $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the only numbers to check are:

$x^2\in[2000,3000):46,48,50,52,54$

$x^2\in[4000,5000):64,66,68,70$

$x^2\in[6000,7000):78,80,82$

$x^2\in[8000,9000):90,92,94$

From which $50,70,90$ can be removed immediately and $80$ is true immediately so essentially only $11$ numbers to check.

Comment: Well, but first we will need to calculate which squares are in the specified ranges, like how can I know that $62$ or $74$ should not be included?

Comment: @l1mbo $\sqrt{4000} > 63$ and $\sqrt{5000} < 71$, so neither 62 nor 74 are possible. Also, note that you can also eliminate 46 and 66 as you know the last digit cannot be 6.

Comment: Got it, thanks @A.J.

Comment: Note if $n =10a + b$ then $n^2 =100a^2 + 20ab + b^2$.  The firs digit of $b^2$ carries and can not be odd.  So $b= 4,6$ are impossible. so you are down to $48,52,68,78,82,92$ or only $6$ cases to check.